# Deleting data from database using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm stuck with an issue relating to deleting data from my database

> The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. -

My controller for deleting -

```
public function destroy($id) {

        $project = Projects::findOrFail($id);
        $project->delete();
        return redirect('/')->with('msg', 'Your project is now done');
   }
```

My form for deleting the data -

```
form action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}" method="POST">

            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button>Finish your project</button>
        </form>
```

My route -

```
Route::delete('/projects/{id}', [ProjectController::class, 'destroy']);
```

Migration -

```
public function up() {

        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('assignment');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->json('extra');
        });
    }
```

And lastly my models -

```
class Projects extends Model {

    use HasFactory;
    protected $casts = [
        'extra' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tested by using POST method ?

Comment: What's that `@method('DELETE')` in your form code?

Comment: the @method('DELETE') is meant to sutitude the normal method="POST" in the form

Comment: @AmedeAngelAulerien Isn't the POST method meant to POST data into the database + I fake POST in the form and changing the POST into a @method('DELETE') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `php artisan cache:clear` at some point when debugging, which enables and clears cache. So the changes in my web.php routes file were not being applied, as they were cached.

Ty for the help guys ! :)

Comment: To sum it up, I ran "php artisan route:clear" and it fixed it up nicely

Answer (score 1):

try this

Controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request) {

  $project = Projects::findOrFail($request->id);
  $project->delete();
  return redirect('/')->with('msg', 'Your project is now done');

}
```

View

```
<form action="/projects/delete" method="POST">  
  @csrf
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $project->id }}"/> 
  <button>Finish your project</button>
</form>
```

Route

```
Route::post('/projects/delete', [ProjectController::class, 'destroy']);
```

Comment: This gave me the same error message - The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: just change this
<button type="submit">Finish your project</button>

Comment: also can you please share error message with me

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - https://gyazo.com/c914ce46edefd7bebf6903d3eefa5fbc here's a screenshot of the error message

Comment: Route::post('/projects/delete', [ProjectController::class, 'drop]);
public function drop(Request $request)

please change the name destroy into drop

Comment: i have test the code  mention error in screenshot https://i.imgur.com/PscB3zc.png only happen if route define like this https://i.imgur.com/U9kteIq.png

Comment: With this the same error comes up for me? it's as if it wants me to change the POST into GET or HEAD ??

Comment: yes you have to change route get into post like this

Route::post('/projects/delete', [ProjectController::class, 'destroy']);

Comment: can you please share your route file screenshot with me

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1c7b73102a341bd0db7a4a6b56946f3f - My routes

Comment: route file is fine i'm expecting view file look like this https://i.imgur.com/tqmxVeP.png